# GSON one to one relationship

Tags: json, gson

I want to know what should be the `JSON` structure for `Gson` library to work with one to one relationship (also know as **belongsTo**).

This is my model

```
public class Course {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    private Teacher teacher;

    //...setters and getters
}


public class Teacher {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String lastName;

    //...setters and getters
}
```

until now, my `JSON` format for filling a `Course` using `gson.fromJSON(string,Course.class)` is the following:

```
{ 
    "id":1,
    "name":"Math"
}
```

how can I also fill a `Teacher` ?

Comment: I hate to point out the obvious but ... Just use Gson and serialize your class to see the JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your JSON was structured like this, I believe GSON should handle it properly.

```
{ 
    "id":1,
    "name":"Math",
    "teacher": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe"
    }
}
```